# Defining the Subgradient with Polar of the Tagent Cone on the Epigraph, or the Convex Hull

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, subgradient, non-smooth-analysis

To start, I would like to state both definitions for sub-gradient and where they came from.

#### Definition 1

> Let $f$ be $\mathbb E \mapsto \mathbb {\bar R}$ with $x\in \text{dom}(f)$ then $v\in \mathbb E$ is a sub-gradient at $x$ when:
> $$
>     f(y) \ge f(x) + \langle v, y- x\rangle + o(\Vert y - x\Vert) \text{ as }y \rightarrow x
> $$
> There is no subgradient for $x\not\in \text{dom}(f)$

**My comments**:

$o$ being the small o notations, it means that $\lim_{y\rightarrow x}o(\Vert y - x\Vert)/\Vert y - x\Vert = 0$. This is depicting the pictures of infinitely many trajectories of particles $y$ approaching $x$ in the domain of $\text{dom}(f)$ with some "headlights" pointing along the direction of their velocities (a cone 90-degree cone headlights) intersecting and forms the set of all possible sub-gradient. It's just the polar of the tangent cone at $x$ for the epigraph of $f$.

**Source**:
Dmitriy Drusvyatskiy's course notes at the University of Washington in his Convex Analysis class.

---

#### Definition 2

> Let $f$ be proper and $x\in \text{dom}(f)$, then $g$ is a sub-gradient of $f$ at $x$ if:
>
> $$
>     f(y) \ge f(x) + \langle g, y - x\rangle  \;\forall y \in \mathbb E
> $$
> There is no subgradient for $x\not\in \text{dom}(f)$

**Source**: <First Order Method in Optimizations> by SIAM

**Comments**

These 2 definitions are obviously different, and under the case where $f$ is convex, they are the same. There are several details here, firstly the first definition doesn't mention about $f$ being proper. In addition, the second one is describing all the normal of a hyperplane touching the epigraph of $f$ which separates the epigraph of $f$ from very other points outside of the convex closure of the epigraph. In fact, the second definition is a smaller set of sub-gradients compared to the first one.

**My questions are**:

1. Firstly, are they both correct? if so do we have different types of sub-gradient?
2. If $f$ is not convex, which one should we use and why the difference between them would be important? (Or may it's not important at all when $f$ is non-convex)

Comment: I have never seen the first in the context of convex functions in finite dimensional spaces. There is a notion of generalised gradient for locally Lipschitz functions, but that is either via majorisation by the generalised directional derivative or accumulation point of gradients.

Comment: Huh... Would you kindly tell me more about the: "Generalized Gradient for Locally Lipschitz functions" and "Majorisation" ?

Comment: Look at https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1975-205-00/S0002-9947-1975-0367131-6/S0002-9947-1975-0367131-6.pdf maybe.